# Mostrar el nombre de la persona logueada con php

Tags: php, html

[image: Mi problema está en la parte de arriba, quiero poner el nombre de la persona logueada]

```
<?php

    require_once "conexion.php";
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {

    } else {

      echo "Inicia sesion para ver este contenido<br>";
      echo "<br><a href='index.php'>Login</a>";
      echo "<br><br><a href='index.php'>Registrarme</a>";
      header('Location: http://localhost/control_admin/index.php');//redirige a la página de login si el usuario quiere ingresar sin iniciar sesion
exit;
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Control de ventas</title>
```

Ese es el principio de mi index, el menu donde quiero que aparezca el nombre lo mando a llamar con un include.

Por el momento es todo lo que tengo de php:

```
<?php  
          require_once "conexion.php";
          session_start();

        ?>


        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-white topbar mb-4 static-top shadow">

          <!-- Sidebar Toggle (Topbar) -->
          <button id="sidebarToggleTop" class="btn btn-link d-md-none rounded-circle mr-3">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </button>
```

En la parte que dice bienvenido es donde quiero mostrar el nombre:

```
<span class="mr-2 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small">Bienvenido></span>
                <img class="img-profile rounded-circle" src="img/usuario.png">
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Dónde está el nombre de la persona? Tienes que buscarlo y mostrarlo... ¿dónde intentas hacer eso? ¿cuál es el error?

Comment: Que tal, mi problema es como mandarlo llamar de la base de datos para mostrarlo donde mencionaba en la descripción. Se supone ya se logueo pero no sé como poner esa variable ahí donde necesito.

Comment: Tienes que: 1. Conectar a la BD; 2. Escribir una consulta `SELECT nombre ...` con un `WHERE` como criterio donde uses algún dato que ya tienes para encontrar el nombre, por ejemplo `WHERE usuario=elDatoQueTienes` ; 3. Tomar el valor de la columna `nombre` ; 4. Mostrarlo donde quieres ... Te toca a ti hacerlo y si tienes algún problema nos dices cuál y te ayudamos.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo guiate de esto, creo que te puede servir

```
<h6>Bienvenido, <?=$_SESSION['loggedin']['Nombre'].' '.$_SESSION['loggedin']['Apellidos'];?></h6>
```

Comment: Buen día, amigo. La parte donde dice nombre y apellido tienen que venir al name que puse en los text donde se ingresan esos datos?

Comment: @christianfabela  no amigo, son los campos de la tabla de tu base de datos.

Comment: Al momento de querer validar el login tu lo que haces es una consulta a la base de datos, luego obtienes una fila de resultado como un array asociativo, algo parecido a esto $usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login);  cuando lo tengas lo guardas en la variable de sesion $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;